# Convert string timestamp into unix timestamp in PHP

Tags: php, unix

Im currently struggeling with timestamps. I have Googled for a simple answer for this, but cant find any solution for my problem. I want to convert user input into UNIX time. The user inputs for example "26/03/1982", how do I convert this input into UNIX timestamp?

```
//User input
$birthday = "26/03/1982"; // d/m/y
$birthday = [CONVERTED TO UNIX]
```

Short and simple question. I will add more if you'd like. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into the PHP function [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

> strtotime — Parse about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp

I'm not sure how well it handles `/` in dates, but replace them with `-` and it'll work.

### Example

```
echo strtotime(str_replace("/","-","26/03/1982"));
```

outputs 385977600 which is the Unix date for **Fri, 26 Mar 1982**

*You may need to set your [`date_default_timezone`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) for this to work*

Comment: @AndersGranli check out my edit

Comment: Thanks! Noted and learned! Thanks again for this simple solution! :)